# Application of Optional stopping theorem and exponential martingale (Durret exercise)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

I was trying to solve Durrett problem $4.8.8$, where I have to show that

> Let $S_n= \xi_1 + \ldots \xi_n$  random walk. Suppose $\varphi(\theta_0)=E[\exp(\theta_0 \xi_1)]$ for some $\theta_0<0$ and $\xi_i$ non constant. Then the exponential martingale $X_n=\exp(\theta_0 S_n)$ is a martingale. Let $\tau= \inf \{ n \in \mathbb{N}: S_n \notin(a,b) \}$ and $Y_n=X_{n \wedge \tau}$. Prove that $E[X_\tau]=1$ and $P(S_{\tau} \leq a) \leq \exp(-\theta_0 a)$

---

By OST I have that $E[X_{n \wedge \tau}]=E[X_0]=1$.

First, $n \wedge \tau \rightarrow_n \tau$, and $X_{n \wedge  \tau} \leq \exp(\theta_0b)$ and by DCT, I have:
\begin{align}
E[X_{\tau}]=E[\lim_n X_{n \wedge \tau} ]= \lim_n E[X_{n \wedge \tau}] = 1
\end{align}

To prove the other point, I sould use that $E[X_{\tau}]=1$. What I tried so far is 
\begin{align}
X_{\tau}=\exp(-\theta_0 S_{\tau}) 1_{\tau \leq a} + \exp(-\theta_0 S_{\tau}) 1_{\tau \geq b}
\end{align}

But now I am in trobule because is easy to bound the expectation of the first term, but for the other term I just know that $S_\tau \geq b$ and this is a problem.

How can I move?

Comment: It's relevant to note that $\tau < \infty$ a.s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not actually a problem: The larger $E(\exp(\theta_0 S_{\tau})1_{S_{\tau}\geq \beta})$ is, the worse for the probability that $S_{\tau}\leq a$. Note that your signs in the exponentials aren't entirely consistent. I'm using the ones from your problem statement.

Note that
$$
P(S_{\tau}\leq a)\leq \exp(-a \theta_0)E \exp(\theta_0 S_{\tau})1_{S_{\tau}\leq a},
$$

since $t\mapsto \exp(\theta_0 t)$ is decreasing. Now,

$$
\exp(-a \theta_0)E \exp(\theta_0 S_{\tau})1_{S_{\tau}\leq a}\leq \exp(-a\theta_0) E(\exp(\theta_0S_{\tau}))=\exp(-a\theta_0)E(X_{\tau})=\exp(-a\theta_0),
$$

Comment: In the last line, first inequality: why do you have the indicator of $\tau \geq a$?

Comment: It's a typo. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Another question

In  $P(S_{\tau}\leq a)\leq \exp(-a \theta_0)E \exp(\theta_0 S_{\tau})1_{S_{\tau}\leq a}$, why do you come up with $\exp(-a \theta_0)$ ? I can't understand where does it come from

Comment: Well, we are using that $\exp(\theta_0 (S_\tau-a))1_{S_{\tau}\leq a}\leq 1_{S_{\tau}\leq a}$. Depending on $\theta_0$ and $a$, it need not be true that $\exp(\theta_0 S_{\tau})\geq 1$ when $S_{\tau}\leq a$ (and when it *is* true, the above bound is an improvement).

Comment: Thanks, wasn't possible a more direct computation? Because this seems still a bit tricky to me

Comment: Anyway, I assume my argument to apply OST was okay, right?

Comment: Yes. All that's perfectly swell. It's possible you can do it more directly. This was the first thing that came to my mind. But exploiting that a certain event forces a certain variable to have a certain range is a fairly standard probabilistic argument that you should, in any case, grow accustomed to.